# Неправильный vintage mode в sublime text 3

Tags: vim, sublime-text

В sublime text при включенном vintage mode неправильно работает команда s.

А именно: при "выделении текста" > "нажатие s" -- она должна удалять выделенный текст и переходить в режим ввода.

Вместо этого она удаляет выделенный текст + следующий символ, либо выделенный текст за исключением первого символа. Зависит от того выделять слева направо или справа налево.

Илюстрация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть возможность что то с этим сделать? Может в настройках где то.

Может есть хороший плагин для vintage mode вместо стандартного?

PS Да и вообще почему этот глюк не правят? Неужели никого кроме меня это не напрягает?

Comment: Я Sublime не пользуюсь, но в Vim вместо `s` использую `c`, который делает то же самое. Может `c` правильно работает? "> Да и вообще почему этот глюк не правят? Неужели никого кроме меня это не напрягает?" -- вполне возможно. Баг можно зарепортить сюда https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/DefaultPackages/issues

Comment: Нашел отдельный репозиторий для Vintage, там этот баг есть https://github.com/sublimehq/Vintage/issues/151 . Есть даже pull request, только про него похоже все забыли.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно вставить этот код в *.sublime-keymap файл

```
// fix key vim key binding
{ "keys": ["s"], "command": "set_action_motion", "args": {
    "action": "enter_insert_mode",
    "action_args": {"insert_command": "right_delete"},
    "motion": "expand_selection" },
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
}
```